# How to display text field in django_tables2

Tags: django-tables2

I'm using django_table2 to display data from a mysql database. One of the columns is a text column. Data from the text column is displayed without any line breaks. I know django has the `linebreaks` filter. My template just does `{% render_table table %}` so using that filter is not an option. django_tables2 has several options for different column types like `tables.BooleanColumn` but I don't see an option for text columns. All I'd really like to get is the line breaks to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `TemplateColumn` to render any custom template in a column - for example, if you want to use the linebreaks template filter, try something like this:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
  text_field = tables.TemplateColumn('{{ record.text_field|linebreaks }}')
  ...
```